# ASP.NET viewstate proxy server responds 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, proxy, viewstate

ASP.NET viewstate proxy server responds 413 Request Entity Too Large

Hello, there:
A classic ASP.NET 4.6.2 application that working on Internet Explorer.
Customer Environment is Windows Server 2016, .NET Framework 4.6.2

A webpage containing asp.net DataGrid that always sends large viewstate request to web server in postbacking. In one of the customer environments (networking https encrypted, saml shibboleth authentication), the page sometimes "Webpage has expired" to be displayed after a user leaves the page several minutes, then clicks one of its controls (sending request to the server).

When it occurs, Internet Explorer 11 developper tool Network tab shows "413 Request Entity Too Large".

I have modified uploadReadAheadSize value on the server IIS but no effect, probably because the error is not from Web server, but one of the proxy servers or network devices in customer network. IIS log shows no entry when the phenomenon occurs.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/IIS-Support-Blog/Solution-for-Request-Entity-Too-Large-error/ba-p/501134

Currently we have planned to stop using Viewstate and minimizing the webpage request size. It requires to implement paging and other functions that was formerly provided by one of DataGrid functions. But that is a bad bet, because it requires to minimize 1/20 request size if we believe our latest research limiting request size in the customer environment.(not enough research...) We don't have the accurate threshold value of the request size.

The customer might help us if we can show them the network device limiting the request size. Is there any method of networking tools or commands that trace the route of https request and its traffic limitation?

Any ideas?

Comment: Since it is an Asp.net application, try to set the httpRuntime  maxRequestLength property, more detail information, please check these links: [link1](https://forums.asp.net/t/1942234.aspx?The+remote+server+returned+an+error+413+Request+Entity+Too+Large) and [link 2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521725/Request-Entity-Too-Large). Besides, you could also post your question to [Asp.net Forum](https://forums.asp.net/).

Comment: Thank you for your information. We calcurated the size of  request by content-length(bytes) with IE developper tool. But it seems that current web.config httpRuntime maxRequestLength(kilobytes) might be useful for testing the threshold of the circumstance.  I will try ASP.NET forum later.